# Why do characters of groups have modulus $1$?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, characters

This is a fairly simple question, and it is supposed to be a definition-level question. But it really bothers me as I couldn't see the reason. Let $f$ be a character of an (arbitrary) group $G$, then
$$f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$$
and $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$. Apostol in his book Introduction to Number Theory mentions that for all group elements $|f(a)|=1$. The only proof of this statement I can come up with is that if $G$ is a finite abelian group, then for all $g\in G$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $g^n=1_G$. Therefore, we have
$$f(g^n)=f(g)^n=f(1_G)=1$$
Thus $|f(g)|=|1|^{1/n}=1$. However, this result is restricted to only finite abelian groups. So I'm wondering if this is a general truth or it is just for finite abelian groups?

Comment: This might be a duplicate. Thanks in advance if you found a suitable one.

Comment: The characters that Apostol uses may actually be [Dirichlet characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character). In which case your proof is good.

Comment: @Somos No he actually introduces Dirichlef characters after this. This is a note he writes to find the multiplicative inverse of an arbitrary character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a general result for *compact* groups since in that case, the image of $G$ under $f$ must be compact and every compact sub-group of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is contained in $S^1$.

To see this, note that if $H$ is a sub-group of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ and $z\in H$ satisfies $|z|\neq 1$ ,then, $|z^n|$ tends to either $0$ or $\infty$. However, this means that either $H$ is unbounded or has $0$ as an accumulation point (in fact, considering $z^{-1}$, both of these statements must be true). Hence, $H$ cannot be compact.

To see that it's not true in general, simply take $G=\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ and $f(z)=z$. It's clearly a character and its image is not contained in $S^1$.

Comment: Great answer, though really topological. I'm learning number theory. But the idea is essentially the same. I will accept this after the time limit.

Comment: In other words, compact is as good as finite (once again)

Comment: @YourongZang: After a while, you will begin to see that it is not so easy to disentangle number theory from topology. Topology is applied to understand number theory (e.g. using algebraic geometry), and number theory is applied to understand topology (e.g. in algebraic topology).

Comment: Well, compact groups and continuous homomorphisms (or are the homomorphisms automatically continuous when the group is assumed compact?)

Comment: @LeeMosher I will try my best to see that.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft If someone were to write "character", I would assume that it's continuous yeah, and then assume that the group is discrete if the group doesn't carry any other natural topology.

Comment: Sure, but I wanted to make sure this was explicit in this context, since the original context had no topology in the picture (at least none specified), and it does happen that one needs to consider non-continuous characters (though I would agree that it is very rare).

Comment: Note that there is no general statement for non-compact groups. If $G$ is the sub-group of $S^1$ generated by $e^{i \frac{p}{q}\pi}$ for $p\in \mathbb{Z}$, $q\in \mathbb{N}$, then Yourong's argument shows you that every homomorphism  from $G$ into $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ (the characters on $G$ in the discrete topology) still has image in the circle.